# Core Data: Segue to detail controller with newly created ManagedObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, core-data

#### Situation

1. User taps button to add an item to a table view.
2. Table view controller adds the item and segues directly to the edit/detail view controller.

Items are Core Data objects populated with `NSFetchedResultsController`.

#### Question

How do I get a valid reference to the new object so I can perform the segue? I'm looking for the common pattern, and not to violate any Core Data rules.

#### Code

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
  var context: NSManagedObjectContext!
  var frc: NSFetchedResultsController!  // set up fetch request etc.

  // User initiated
  func addItem(_ sender: Any) {
    context.perform {
      let item = Item(context: context)
      try! context.save()
    }

    // How to get hold of the new item and where to initiate the segue?
  }

  func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any) {
    // Pass new item to detail view controller
  }

  // NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods
  // refresh table on updates
}
```

#### Thoughts

**1)** Assuming `context` is the main view context is this safe and correct?

```
var newItem: Item?

func addItem(_ sender: Any) {
  context.perform {
    newItem = Item(context: context)
    try! context.save()  // error handling etc.
    performSegue(...) 
  }
}

func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any) {
  // ...
  detailController.item = newItem
}
```

The perform block would be executed on the context`s queue which is the main queue which would make grabbing the object out of the closure and doing the segue safe, right?

**2)** Or this?

```
context.performAndWait {
  newItem = Item(context: context)
  try! context.save()
}

performSegue(...)
```

For **1)** and **2)**: What if this was not the main context? Would I be able to transfer the object to the main thread/view controller at all?

**3)** Grab the object in the FRC delegate:

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
   // Assuming insert
   new Item = object
   performSegue(...)
}
```

How do I know `object` is the one I just inserted and want to segue with, not just some object inserted by other means? Can I be sure that when I insert an object the very next call to the delegate method would refer to that object? There could be a parallel context inserting an element...

#### Reference

The basic setup without Core Data I'm trying to recreate:

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {
  var tableViewData = [Item]()
  let newItem: Item?

  // On user button press
  func addItem(_ sender: Any) {
    newItem = Item()
    tableViewData.append(newItem)
    tableView.reloadData()
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail")         
  }

  func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any) {
    // ...
    detailController.item = newItem
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, this could be clearer:

```
//On user button press
func addItem() { 
     performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail")
}

func prepare(for segue: UIStoryBoardSegue, sender: Any) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
    //create the item(managedobject), save the context

    //feed the item to the destination viewcontroller who needs it
    }
}
```

That way you know the object you segue with is the right one, and you have the logic closer together.

Ref contexts. When you create a managedObjectContext, you specify how you'll use it (main or private), and you have to stick to that. It's best practice to have one context, that you pass down the viewcontroller hierarchy.

You might need a second context when you start thinking about syncing the data on the device with a backend database, which I think is not the case yet. 
Probably, you will want to make this second context to be a private queue one, and only then you need to worry about mapping the managedobjects to the right context.

Until then, your one and only context is a very friendly animal.

Comment: Thanks! So there's no need to wrap with a `context.perform` block if I'm only dealing with a main context? Getting conflicting answers from SO and now starting to read the objc.io Core Data book. They mention that it's good habit to use `perform` even on main context and to react to changes only from change notifications (e.g. FetchedResultsController or custom one) and not to transfer objects out of the block. I find this disconnect between event and change notification rather confusing. How do I know a change was initiated by the user and not some other background work (e.g. sync)?

Comment: Yup, it's good habit and I also have it. But it's not obligatory.
Actually, in this case, you have to be careful NOT to wrap the insert inside the performBlock, because performBlock is asynchronous and you need the reference to the newly created managedObject straight away.
But you can still wrap the context save inside a performBlock (and that's what I do).

Regarding the other good habit, of only communicating between contexts by merging their did-save notifications, it's oh so true and it brings so much clarity. But, if you really need to, you can break that good habit also.